# Anatomy of an Android Run Loop

Tags: java, android

I can't seem to find any documentation on the details of an Activity's run loop for Android.

Apple documents the "[anatomy of a run loop](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Multithreading/RunLoopManagement/RunLoopManagement.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000057i-CH16-SW20)", and that's pretty much what I'm looking for.  The Android documentation just says "[Activity Is Running](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ActivityLifecycle)" in its life cycle state diagram.  Obviously that's backed up by some sort of run loop.

Anyone have some insight (aka Documentation) into the internals of an Activity's run loop?

edit - I should clarify that I presume the run loop is actually owned and run by the main UI thread.  The current Activity's functionality is likely injected into this runloop at a certain point.  I'm interested in the overall UI thread run loop, as well as what role the Activity takes in it.

Comment: I must be missing something. What more detail is needed than "Activity is Running"?

Why does it matter what Android is doing in that loop, as long as you `implement` or `extend` the appropriate things to let your app do what it needs to do?

Comment: Because when you're writing threaded applications, the characteristics of run loops can be useful information for a wide variety of reasons.  That said, I think curiosity alone would be a valid reason.

Comment: Asking for "insight into the internals of an Activity's run loop" is much too broad of a question.

Comment: No it's not.  Apple managed to provide a succinct answer to exactly what I'm asking.  I'm asking if there is equivalent documentation for Android.  That's in no way too broad.

Comment: Well the android platform is open source, you could always take a look at the Activity class

Comment: @Falmarri here it is: http://www.google.com/codesearch/p?hl=en#uX1GffpyOZk/core/java/android/app/Activity.java&q=android%20activity.java&d=0

Comment: @Falmarri Appreciate the links.  Was hoping that there was a more digested version of it.  Still, if there isn't, if you can post the link in an answer and state as much, I'll accept that.  Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The short answer is, "don't worry about it, it's done for you."

Activities and other constructs sit on top of [`android.os.Looper`](http://d.android.com/reference/android/os/Looper.html), communicating with it through instances of [`android.os.Handler`](http://d.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html). A `Looper` manages your "run loop," dispatching messages from a queue and blocking the thread when it's empty. `Handler`s communicate with a thread's `Looper` and provide a mechanism for working with the message queue.

Most of the time you won't need to work with either one directly. Lifecycle events for your major application components like Activities and Services will be dispatched to your code. If you're curious as to what's under the hood, sources for both are available:

https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/os/Looper.java

https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/os/Handler.java

Comment: I was hoping there was a more digested version of this info, but if there isn't there isn't and that's the answer.  Thanks adamp.

Answer (score 0):

Updated:

There's really nothing specific being referred to by "Activity is running." The Activity is simply displaying its UI, handling input, executing any necessary functions, and starting another Activity.

If you're interested in what implications multi-threading would have on the run-loop, there isn't really a concrete relationship. Your threads can just do their work, and the Activity's state will function independently and automatically update its UI (provided you call `postInvalidate()` correctly).

---

Original:

Take a look at the first diagram on this page: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html

It specifies the "lifetime" of each Activity and what states it can be in, if that's what you're looking for.

Comment: Which is what I linked to... I want to know what's going on in the "Activity is Running" part of that.

Comment: No problem Andy.  There's definitely an underlying run loop though, and I'm sure it looks similar to the one I linked for iphone.  Activities "running" state is presumably injected into the global UI Thread's runloop, but it certainly has its own set of steps on each loop to check for callbacks, state, etc.  I'm curious what that whole shebang looks like.